# Execute a command before a git push?

Tags: bash, git, github, zsh

Every time I `git push` I have a file larger than 100MB, so I was wondering, how can I add this command `find . -type f -size +100M -exec ls -sh {} \;` before every `git push` command ?

I can't do it in an alias, as `git` and `push` are 2 separates strings, and even if I create an alias for `push`, `push` will not be recognized as an alias if I do a `git push`.

If I do it in a script, this is the same, I can't call my script "git push" with blank right?
Because ' ' = '\ ' in shell

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Add it to a function and put it in ~/.bashrc

Comment: You shuold take a look at git hooks.

Comment: [Use Git Large File Storage instead](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uLR1RNqJ1Mw).

Comment: `Every time I git push I have a file larger than 100MB` - what exactly does this mean? What is the purpose of executing that before pushing? If for example you are getting an error message, please put that in the question. Why you are asking what you are asking is probably more relevant to the way you are trying to solve it.

Comment: indeed it is not every time but, it can happen to me, and often I do not need to push these large files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as "executing a script go", you can :

- create a git alias :

```
# one hacky way to turn your command in a (bad) one liner :
git config alias.pushcheck '! find . -type f -size +100M -exec ls -sh {} \; | grep . && echo "*** Large files detected, rejecting push" || git push'
```

- create a `git-pushcheck` script, and place it on your `PATH`,
  you can then use it as if you had a new `git pushcheck` subcommand
- for `push` specific actions, you can write a `pre-push` hook

---

As for the logic behind your action :

- `find` would also look inside your `.git/` local directory, so a packfile which happens to be bigger than 100M would block your action,
- it would also look into `gitignore`d files

so depending on what you want to achieve, you may need to write a more targeted script.

If you have issues with handling big files, you probably want to use `git lfs` as @Schwern suggested in his comment.

Please edit your question (or ask a new one) to provide more informations on your use case if you need more details on how to handle your use case.

Comment: thanks for your answer ! I had indeed seen the 'git aliases' but I did not see how to create one for me, this corresponds to what I wanted to do, thank you